# Does PySpark append write mode allows duplicates to the output file

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

This is a basic question related to PySpark Write modes. So when writing the below code

`spark.write.mode('append').csv('dummy.csv')`

If the above function is executed twice for the same dataset. Will it create duplicates in the output file

Duplicate values or not

Comment: Yes executing the above code twice with the same input dataframe will create duplicate data in your output file.